# Find words and copy into next column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to find and copy text into next column in Excel. I have column A, with text or sentences. I want to find a particular word and copy that word into the next column that is column B only if that word is available in the text of Column A.

I have this solution for single word search and copy but I want to apply this for multiple search and copy of different words:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("processes", A4)), MID(A4, SEARCH("processes", A4), 9), "")
```

Example:

Suppose Column A contains text like this:

```
"Execution of procedure and processes".
"All Procedures are correctly updated" 
"Processes are going smoothly".
```

I want to search for word as `"Processes and procedure"` and that should copy in Column B (cell 1) "ONLY IF" either `processes` or `procedure` is in the text.

Could you please help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to return one of those words, you can use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Processes","Procedures"},A4)),{"Processes","Procedures"})
```

Or, you can, for example, put the search words into cells:

```
C1:  Processes
D1:  Procedures

=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$D$1,A4)),$C$1:$D$1)
```

The formula will return an error if neither word is there; and it can be expanded to any number of words.  If you don't like the plain error message, you can wrap the above in an IFERROR function and return what you like.

The SEARCH function with a array for find_text will return an array of either a number, or #VALUE!  The ISNUMBER function will then return an array of TRUE or FALSE.  The division operation (1/ISNUMBER) will return an array of 1 or #DIV/0!  LOOKUP with a lookup_value of 2 will then find the last location of a number that is equal to or less than 2; and return from the result_vector the item in the same position.

If you need to return both words, and they can be in different cells, enter this **array** formula, and fill right for the number of words in your search list:

e.g:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IF(SEARCH($C$1:$D$1,$A4),$C$1:$D$1,""),1,COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula.

**EDIT:** *Screen Shot added*

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It helps a bit. I tried this solution and it works. The only problem is that if both words are present then it gives last word only. like in this example it gives a word as a result as procedure only. Is there any way to get both words? It is fine to get it into different cells.

Comment: @Sharmil  See the addition to my answer

Comment: I tried with suggested formula but could not get result. =IFERROR(INDEX(IF(SEARCH("procedures", "Processes",$A1),$A$1:$A$1,""),1,COLUMNS($A:A)),""). Also I tried with your formula as well.

Comment: @Sharmil The formula you show in your comment is not the one in my answer.  In particular, you did not enter the strings as an array constant.

Comment: I tried with this as well.{=IFERROR(INDEX(IF(SEARCH( "processes","procedures",$A1),$C$1:$D$1,""),1,COLUMNS($A:A)),"")}

Comment: @Sharmil In your latest comment, how did you get the braces around the formula?  Both formulas, when entered properly, work on the examples you provided.

Comment: @Sharmil I have added a screen shot showing the application of the formula to your data, according to how I have interpreted your requirements.  If this is not what you want, you will need to be more specific, or provide a copy of your workbook.

Comment: @ Ron: Thank you. This snap worked a lot. where there is no match it will show zero. correct?

Comment: @Sharmil Not exactly:  If there is no match, a blank cell will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally say don't hardcode values into your formulas. A formula which should return as you asked is below. Place formula into **B1** and drag down.

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISERR(FIND("processes",LOWER($A1)))),NOT(ISERR(FIND("procedure",LOWER($A1))))), IF(NOT(ISERR(FIND("processes and procedure",LOWER($A1)))),"processes and procedure",""),"")
```

This formula is checking if "processes" or "procedure" can be found in the string in column **A**, if this is the case it will check if the string "processes and procedure" occurs (which it doesn't in your example!) and if it does, it will return "processes and procedure"

Going back to my original point, I would suggest putting `"process"` into cell **C1**, `"procedure"` into cell **D1** and `"processes and procedure"` into cell **E1** the formula would look like this:

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISERR(FIND(C1,LOWER($A1)))),NOT(ISERR(FIND(D1,LOWER($A1))))), IF(NOT(ISERR(FIND(E1,LOWER($A1)))),E1,""),"")
```

This way you can edit columns **C, D and E** and your formulas will recalculate

Test these formulas with a value such as `"Execution of processes and procedures"` in cell **A1**

UPDATE: this is what your setup should look like, as per my example.

[image]

UPDATE: since you can't see the image, essentially make sure you set up columns **A, C, D & E** as follows and then paste the formula into column **B**

```
              A                            C            D            E
Execution of processes and procedures  processes   procedures  processes and procedures
Execution of procedures and processes  processes   procedures  processes and procedures
```

Comment: I tried with your second suggestion but it is not working. It is not returning any word but it is showing as ZERO. For first formula it returns result as processes and procedures. But I like your recommendation in second formula which works for me. Could you please take a look?

Comment: I've added a screenshot, to give you a better idea of how I've set it up. If ZERO is showing, it could be that you've not put anything in columns C,D and E. Let me know if it still isn't working for you

Comment: Could you please add snap shot again? I am not able to download it.

Comment: I have added again without a snapshot